# graphQL query give me null object in response

Tags: sequelize.js, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I'm newbie in graphql and have following problem:

**I'm querying all customers with their photo but graphql server response give me null on photo object.**

If I try the RAW SQL statement from Sequelize logging  and execute in my sql client it give me right result.

I think the problem is somewhere in graphql on client but I dont know where.

I didnt add till now custom scalar type for field **filetype** in CustomerPhoto schema but I dont think that this is a issue.

// Customer schema

```
import CustomerPhoto from "./customerPhoto";

    const Customer = `
     type Customer {
      customerID: ID!
      firstname: String
      lastname: String
      phone: String
      email: String
      photo: CustomerPhoto
     } 
     type Query {
      customers: [Customer]
      }
    `;

    export default [Customer, CustomerPhoto];

// CustomerPhoto schema

const CustomerPhoto = `
  type CustomerPhoto {
    customerPhotoID: ID!
    filename: String
    filetype: BLOB
  } 
`;

export default CustomerPhoto;
```

Here is my query in grahpiQL:

```
{
  customers {
    firstname
    phone
    photo {
     customerPhotoID
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the result from query:

```
  {
      "data": {
        "customers": [
          {
            "firstname": "Jade",
            "phone": "993.588.1173 x0426",
            "photo": null
          },
          {
            "firstname": "Oleta",
            "phone": "288-162-3631",
            "photo": null
          },
          {
            "firstname": "Geoffrey",
            "phone": "742.195.2920 x40571",
            "photo": null
          },
          {
            "firstname": "Daphne",
            "phone": "010.713.4911 x39353",
            "photo": null
          }
    ......
        ]
      }
    }
```

here is my resolver:

```
const CustomerResolvers = {
  Query: {
    customers: (_, args) => {
      return models.Customer.findAll({
        include: {
          model: models.CustomerPhoto,
          attributes: ["customerPhotoID","filename"],
        },
        attributes: ["customerID","firstname", "lastname", "phone", "email"],
      });

    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I had bad Customer schema

**Here is the solution:**

instead of photos I had to use CustomerPhoto

```
const Customer = `
     type Customer {
      customerID: ID!
      firstname: String
      lastname: String
      phone: String
      email: String
      CustomerPhoto: CustomerPhoto
     } 
     type Query {
      customers: [Customer]
      }
    `;
```